# CORS error for large files

Tags: cors, filepicker.io

While smaller files are uploading ok, sizes larger than 200Mb give the following CORS error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3?key=Ad9Izd38AQzaNycUe6r4Qz&filename=…t_1Gb.fastq.gz&path=uploads/331/test_1Gb.fastq.gz&_cacheBust=1368071391844. Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have the IAM policy set as specified by filepicker documentation.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or similar that generates this error. What OS/Browser are you on? Feel free to continue this conversation via bugs@filepicker.io

Comment: @brettcvz, have you guys figured this out? I have emailed you guys twice about this issue with no reply. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong -- rather, the browser is timing out because Ink's timeout prevention isn't working properly. As a short term solution, try using Chrome. In the medium term, we're working on a fix.

Comment: I'm also suddenly receiving this even with much smaller files, and I *am* using Chrome. Did something change recently (during last 24 hours)? If so, is there a workaround?

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/cw5FQCaToiF3Ud6VkVjn/convert?_cacheBust=1381981494907. Origin https://xxxxxxx.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: Well... while implementing a workaround in my dev sandbox, it suddenly started working again on my production site (which I hadn't changed), so I assume something got fixed on the filepicker.io server.

Comment: @KarlWhite I doubt it's fixed. This is something that has been going on for a while for us. It comes and goes. Sometimes even with smaller files it happens.